# Angular 2 injector error "Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined"

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have this component using a value provider:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: "currency",
    useValue : "dollar"
  }]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

title = "app works";


constructor(private injector: Injector){
 this.title = "Currency is: "+ injector.get("currency");
 }
}
```

When I run the program, the injector throws an error saying, "`Cannot read property 'instance' of undefined`"[image: Error as shown in the console]

If it matters, my view is a simple `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Injector, just import the 'Inject' decorator and use like so-

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{
     provide: "currency",
     useValue : "dollar"
  }]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  title = "app works";


  constructor(@Inject("currency") private currency){
     this.title = "Currency is: "+ currency;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem but why isn't mine working? What is wrong with my procedure?

Comment: The injector is used to inject instances of something, not primitive values. A primitive string not assigned to a variable is just a string, not an instance of a variable or class.

Comment: Your method might work if, outside of the component, you declared  

export const currency = '';

and then in the providers line you specified

provide : currency   (without the quotes)

but i'm not sure